# Show that $1$ and $-1$ are the only divisors of $1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic

I have this from my textbook. I do understand the proof in depth, I also see the logic of how they cancel out all options to eventually show that the statements us true. My problem is the tiny thing marked in yellow on the side, I have a fairly basic understanding of mathematical logic, in the sense that I do know what Implies mean and the difference between converse, contrapositive etc. But somehow I am not fully sure what the logic behind the yellow statement is? **Could someone please related the yellow to the text.**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The idea is that the statements $p$, $q$, and $r$ (each implicitly depending on an integer $x$) are:
$$\begin{align*}
p&=“x\text{ is a divisor of }1”\\\\
q&=“x=1”\\\\
r&=“x=-1”
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Sweet, thats what I thought!